# Where is Note type objects text actually stored?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am looking for a way to query EAs database for text stored in diagram notes (Object Type is Note or Text). However It does not seem to be stored anywhere in t_object table nor are there any tagged values (table t_objectproperties) associated with these notes.

Would you know where to look? Thanks.

Update:
So it is actually stored in t_object.Note but for some reason you cannot access that from EA's SQL console unless you specify an alias for that column.

Answer (score 3):

Look closer. Notes are stored in `t_object`.

Notes usually have no name, and their content is stored in the `t_object.Note`.

In order to view that column in the EA Scratch pad or search you can select the option "View notes" in the dropdown button on the right, or choose another name as alias for the Note column.

```
Select o.Note AS ShowMeThis from t_object
```

Comment: You are right, EA SQL console just wont let you view that column.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it is actually stored in t_object.Note, but EA's SQL console will not let you access that column, probably because it is a BLOB.